# Seven Kingdoms I (7KAA) does not play music in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, seven-kingdoms-ancient-adversaries

Does anybody know why *7KAA* cannot play its music in Ubuntu while it is fine in Windows?

Game website:
http://7kfans.com

Music locations:

```
/usr/share/7kaa/music
/usr/share/7kaa/music/chinese.wav
/usr/share/7kaa/music/greek.wav
/usr/share/7kaa/music/japanese.wav
/usr/share/7kaa/music/lose.wav
/usr/share/7kaa/music/maya.wav
/usr/share/7kaa/music/norman.wav
/usr/share/7kaa/music/persian.wav
/usr/share/7kaa/music/viking.wav
/usr/share/7kaa/music/war.wav
/usr/share/7kaa/music/win.wav
/usr/share/doc/7kaa-music
/usr/share/doc/7kaa-music/COPYING-Music.txt
/usr/share/doc/7kaa-music/README-Music.txt

/usr/share/games/7kaa/music/chinese.wav
/usr/share/games/7kaa/music/greek.wav
/usr/share/games/7kaa/music/japanese.wav
/usr/share/games/7kaa/music/lose.wav
/usr/share/games/7kaa/music/maya.wav
/usr/share/games/7kaa/music/norman.wav
/usr/share/games/7kaa/music/persian.wav
/usr/share/games/7kaa/music/viking.wav
/usr/share/games/7kaa/music/war.wav
/usr/share/games/7kaa/music/win.wav
```

Comment: Does sound work on the game at all or is it just the music that isn't working? If sound isn't working at all you may want to try installing the 32bit alsa library with `sudo apt-get install libasound2-plugins:i386`. This usually helps when sound isn't working in game on a 64bit system.

Comment: can you check to see if `pulseaudio` is being used or is turned on?